# Volume number should not be displayed in italics with apacite bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style, italic-correction

I am very new to LaTeX, and I'm trying to set up my citation and bibliography format.  The only problem I have left is that my volume/issue is displayed in italics when I use the `apacite` bibliography style.  How can I change this so that this is no longer in italics?

My text is as follows (I'm just trying things out for now):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{thesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\author{Kristian Jensen}
\title{Bibliography in \LaTeX}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}  
\renewcommand{\BBAB}{and} 
\renewcommand{\BAnd}{and}


We are now going to try out how this works by doing a citation.

Here it is: \citep{Pressair}.

That's it for now.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

And from my `mybib.bib` file:

```
@Article{Pressair,
author = {Press, F., and Ewing, M.},
title = {Theory of aircoupled flexural waves},
journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
volume = {22},
number = {7},
year = {1951},
pages = {892-899},
}
```

In my reference list now, everything looks OK except for the volume/issue which is displayed as *22(7)* when I want it to be 22(7) (not italics).  If anyone can help me fix this, then I will really appreciate it!

Comment: An aside: You shouldn't load the `apacite` and `natbib` packages independently. If you want to use natbib-style citation commands, you should load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa` (and, of course, not the `natbib` package as well).

Comment: Incidentally, there are lots and lots of document class files called `thesis` on the Internet. Which one would you happen to be using?

Comment: After fixing a problem in your bib file -- there should be no comma after "Press, F." in the `author` field -- I am unable to fully replicate the issue you say you're encountering. Specifically, the issue number is *not* set in italics, contrary to what you say is happening.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your input!  You are right - the issue number now appears to be correct, but the volume issue is still in italics.  As for the 'natbibapa' suggestion, when I try to enter '\usepackage{natbibapa}' I get an error message that this file is not found (is there something else I have to enter?).  Finally, I don't know which specific document class 'thesis' is.  I just read that this one of the default styles (along with article, book, etc.).  As I said, I'm very, very new to LaTeX, so I'm sorry if my questions are basic.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing sufficiently clear. You need to load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa` as follows: `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`. (There is no package called `natbibapa`.) A separate note: If you don't want the volume number to be typeset in italics, you should consider not using the `apacite` bibliography style to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apacite` package contains a LaTeX macro that determines the default formatting of the `journal`, `volume`, `number`, and `pages` fields for entries of type `@article`. This macro is called `\APACjournalVolNumPages`, and its default definition may be found in `apacite.sty` starting at around line 1275.

To modify this macro, I suggest loading the `etoolbox` package and using that package's `\patchcmd` macro. Specifically, you should insert the following lines of code in the preamble, after having the loaded the `apacite` package:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\APACjournalVolNumPages}%
    {\unskip, \Bem{#2}}%
    {\unskip, #2}{}{}
\makeatother
```

The macro `\Bem` is an alias for `\emph`. Basically, the modification of the `\APACjournalVolNumPages` macro consists in removing the italics emphasis of the second argument -- the contents of the `volume` field.

A full MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@Article{Pressair,
author =  {Press, F. and Ewing, M.},
title =   {Theory of aircoupled flexural waves},
journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
volume =  {22},
number =  {7},
year =    {1951},
pages =   {892--899},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % load "apacite" with option "natbibapa" 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} % specify the bibliography style

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\APACjournalVolNumPages}%
    {\unskip, \Bem{#2}}%
    {\unskip, #2}{}{}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}
    \renewcommand{\BBAB}{and}
    \renewcommand{\BAnd}{and}}

\begin{document}


\citep{Pressair}

\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```